# ExpressJS Server - How to handle multiple domains

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm fooling around a little with Express and I'm wondering, what the "most correct" way is to handle multiple domains which are linked to the same server.

Lets assume we have

- foo.com
- bar.net
- baz.com

which all point to `111.222.333.444`. That machine is running NodeJS with Express. My current solution looks like this:

```
var express = require( 'express' ),
    app     = module.exports = express.createServer(),
// ... more lines ...
app.get( '/', routes.index.bind( app ) );
```

Thus far this is pretty straightforward. The only exception so far is in my `app.configure` call, where I didn't make a call to `.use( express.static() )`. Thats because the `.routes.index()` method looks like so right now:

```
var fs    = require( 'fs' ),
// ... more lines ...

exports.index = function( req, res ) {
    var host = /(\w+\.)?(.*)\.\w+/.exec( req.header( 'host' ) ),
        app  = this;

    switch( host[ 2 ] ) {
        case 'foo':
            app.use( express.static( '/var/www/foo' ) );
            fs.readFile( '/var/www/foo/index.html', 'utf8', fileReadFoo );
            break;
        case 'bar':
            app.use( express.static( '/var/www/bar' ) );
            fs.readFile( '/var/www/bar/index.html', 'utf8', fileReadBar );
            break;
        case 'baz':
            // ... lines ...
            res.render( 'index', { title: 'Baz Title example' } );
            break;
        default:
            res.send('Sorry, I do not know how to handle that domain.');
    }

    function fileReadFoo( err, text ) {
        res.send( text );
    }

    function fileReadBar( err, text ) {
        res.send( text );
    }
};
```

What happens here is, that I analyse the `req.header` for the `host` entry and parse the domain name. Based on that, I call the `.static()` method so *Express* can serve the right static resources etc., furthermore, I just simply read and send the contents of the *index.html* files. I tried to use *Jade* aswell for serving plain *HTML files*, but the `include` directive in *Jade* only accepts relative pathes.

However, this indeed works, but I'm pretty unsure if that is a good practice.

Any advice / help welcome.

---

**Update**

I think I need to make this more clear. I'm not a beginner by any means. I'm very aware how ES works and other servers like NGINX. I'm looking for qualified answers on what the right thing with NodeJS/Express is. If it doesn't make any sense to use Node/Express for that, please elaborate. If there is a better way to do this with Node/Express, please explain.

Thanks :-)

Comment: +1, Interesting way of thinking.

Comment: Why do they have to be all hosted in the same process?  It's not natural to do that in node.  You'll bring your static sites down if the 'baz' site crashes.

Comment: It's still original and might be useful for a specific use case. For instance coordinating several robots. Running the same app several times in the same process. Could be interesting.

Comment: This is not a great solution because of browser caching.If you have two files with the same name - e.g. styles.css - then the foo css might load from cache when you visit bar. I tried this will a SPA app and the problem affects your app.min.js too.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I like to use [bouncy](https://github.com/substack/bouncy) as a front end reverse-proxy - this lets you run totally different express stacks as different server processes (each with different features and separated for robustness)...

You can then decide how to route to different ports, it works fine with WebSockets.

```
var bouncy = require('bouncy');

bouncy(function (req, bounce) {
    if (req.headers.host === 'bouncy.example.com') {
        bounce(8000);
    }
    else if (req.headers.host === 'trampoline.example.com') {
        bounce(8001)
    }
}).listen(80);
```

Comment: Based on @BinoCarlos example, for those curious, I threw together a really simple example for adding and removing multiple hosts quickly and easily. It supports string matching as well as regex and allows you to edit the file without restarting it (if you're using something like `forever`) Check it out: https://gist.github.com/Swivelgames/1cdf37c3317a4f82db89

Answer (score 45):

Vadim was [almost onto the right idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11960705/expressjs-server-how-to-handle-multiple-domains#comment15940267_11960962). You can configure how to respond to each domain with the [`vhost` middleware](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/vhost.html):

```
// `baz.com`
var app = express.createServer();
app.get( '/', routes.index );

// ...

express.createServer()
    .use( express.vhost( 'foo.com', express.static( '/var/www/foo' ) ) )
    .use( express.vhost( 'bar.net', express.static( '/var/www/bar' ) ) )
    .use( express.vhost( 'baz.com', app ) )
    .use( function( req, res ) {
        res.send('Sorry, I do not know how to handle that domain.');
    })
    .listen( ... );
```

`routes.index` can then be simplified to handle only `baz.com` requests:

```
exports.index = function( req, res ) {
    // ... lines ...
    res.render( 'index', { title: 'Baz Title example' } );
};
```

**Edit**

As for comparisons:

The `switch` would effectively be done first and would determine how to handle all requests based on the `host` -- similar to:

```
express.createServer().use(function( req, res, next ) {
    switch( req.host ) {
        case 'foo.com': express.static( '/var/www/foo' )( req, res, next ); break;
        case 'bar.net': express.static( '/var/www/bar' )( req, res, next ); break;
        case 'baz.com': app.handle( req, res, next ); break;
        default: res.send( ... );
    }
}).listen( ... );
```

It allows you to set the stack on start so any middleware is available immediately:

```
server.stack = [
    express.vhost( 'foo.com', ... ),
    express.vhost( 'bar.net', ... ),
    express.vhost( 'baz.com', ... ),
    [Function]
];
```

These also reflect the 2 possible sources of issues you might have:

**Same stack without filters**

Each `Application` only has 1 middleware stack, which all of the middleware you're using is being added directly to with `app.use(...)`. Despite adding some under conditions, you're still getting:

```
app.stack = [
    // ...,
    app.router,
    express.static( '/var/www/foo' ),
    express.static( '/var/www/bar' )
];
```

And the condition won't change how the `static` middlewares respond -- which is by `req.path`, not `req.host` -- only when they're in the stack to start responding.

**State of the stack**

And, if the `static` middlewares aren't added until *after* another request has been made, then I take it they aren't available immediately:

```
// GET http://foo.com/file 404
app.stack = [ app.router ]

// GET http://foo.com/ 200
app.stack = [ app.router, express.static( '/var/www/foo' ) ]

// GET http://foo.com/file 200
app.stack = [ app.router, express.static( '/var/www/foo' ) ]
```

This may also mean the same `static` middleware could be added to the stack multiple times:

```
// 3x GET http://foo.com/
app.stack = [
    app.router,
    express.static( '/var/www/foo' ),
    express.static( '/var/www/foo' ),
    express.static( '/var/www/foo' )
]
```

And having their addition depend on other requests also suggests a possible race conditions:

```
// was `foo.com` or `bar.net` first?
app.stack = [
    app.router,
    express.static( ? ),
    express.static( ? )
]
```

Comment: it looks like it does essentially the same as I do manually there ? Or is there any more magic behind.

Comment: @jAndy It would ensure the `static` middlewares are bound immediately and would only respond to the listed domain. I could be very wrong... But, I think as you have it, you can't request `http://foo.com/file` before requesting `http://foo.com/`. And, I don't think the middlewares retain the domain association they're being bound under, so `http://bar.net/file` may be responding as `http://foo.com/file` if you visit `http://foo.com/` first.

Comment: I don't think I'm understanding your comment.
A middleware doesn't have to retain domain association, simply because each request contains the domain name. 
Requesting `http://foo.com` will correctly result in `Host: foo.com`, and successively requesting `http://bar.net/file` will result in `Host: bar.net`.

Comment: I edited my answer to try to elaborate on my comment. Sorry for the length, but hope it helps clear up what I was trying to say.

Comment: It doesn't support https.

Answer (score 4):

Since Express uses [Connect](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/middleware-vhost.html), I'm pretty sure you can use Connect's virtual host middleware. It operates similar to other vhost modules on other products. I don't have multiple domains to test and show you proper code, but I would think it's something like this:

```
express.createServer()
.use(express.vhost('hostname1.com', require('/path/to/hostname1').app)
.use(express.vhost('hostname2.com', require('/path/to/hostname2').app)
.listen(80)
```

If you get to the point where one Express server isn't enough, then look into using the Node.Cluster from the API. If that also isn't enough, then the current practice is to put a asnyc reverse proxy such as Nginx in front of your Express servers and point the proxies to your Express servers.

Answer (score 4):

It's quite difficult to answer this without knowing the constraints that meant you **must** run the hosts in the same process, so I'll echo what others have said, but hopefully give some more context.

The "most correct" thing to do with node is to run the hosts in multiple processes and to reverse proxy the requests in another process.  Running multiple sites in the same process is riddled with problems, not least of which is a crash in one, brings them all down and requires a restart of the whole process.  Node's philosophy is very unix-like, it encourages keeping programs small and separate.  If you separate the processes, you'll get a natural segregation of applications.  If you pursue a monolithic design, you'll have to write and maintain logic to separate logging from the different sites and error handling logic will become more complicated.  There are no doubt other cases where you'll need to branch logic based on host, but your application design will encourage rather than discourage that.

If you're averse to other technology stacks (or are concerned e.g. by nginx's current lack of support of websockets in the stable branch), then there are a few solid reverse proxys written in nodejs, including nodejitsu's [http-proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy) which is used in their production PaaS stack on Joyent's cloud and [bouncy](https://github.com/substack/bouncy) (mentioned in another answer) which has less features, but I believe is being used in production on browserling.

The author of bouncy actually goes as far as suggesting it as [one of the most important architectural patterns in designing a nodejs system](http://www.quora.com/What-are-some-best-architecture-practices-when-designing-a-nodejs-system).  You may also notice that his answer has been upvoted by some of the core node committers.

Answer (score 3):

I use [nginx](http://nginx.org/) as front-server with node.js. It's the best solution to organize domains, static content delivery, load control and many other powerful features. Absolutely no need to do it in node event loop. This will determine the speed of your application.

Comment: Well, if I'd like to use nginx I wouldn't have asked the question. Thanks for the response anyway. But I really want to figure exactly that this stuff. "Can nodeJS/Express doe this stuff?", "How is the performance?", "Is that the correct way", "etc.".

Comment: Connect/Express have vhost http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/vhost.html middleware to play with domains. But i still recommend use separate server to improve application perfomance.

Comment: Why is Express/Node so slow about this ?

Comment: All code (except I/O operations) blocks event loop (thread). So the event loop should work as fast as possible. It should contains only necessary business logic. More code - slower event loop.

Comment: I don't really see the bottleneck in that (maybe even pure) code. All IO is async aswell as any other code uses async callbacks. So, how could that really affect the loop performance? Thats the NodeJS way..

Comment: In node.js only I/O is async. All other code execute synchronously. Callbacks only delaying code to next tick. But code still works synchronously. Schematically: I/O_____YOUR_CODE_____I/O_____YOUR_CODE.  Application works fast while YOUR_CODE works fast.

Comment: For example try to calculate factorial or fibonacci for each request and check perfomance. All other code does the same thing but slowly.

Comment: I'm well aware of how ecmascript works. Still, there is no heavy calculation in this code, it should be lightening fast.

Answer (score 3):

I would not recommend using Express in the first place. In fact, even for a single domain, using Node's http module, one can easily write an app with all the functionality that you get with Express.

For multiple domains, once you get the hostname, you can customize your routes or middleware or whatever you want to call them. As long as you do not have any blocking calls in any of the app, the number of domains your singe node process is going to serve is irrelevant. If CPU usage becomes a bottleneck, you can use cluster of the same process.

Clustering is not possible if you have in-memory session data. You will need another process to maintain state of which instance is managing that particular session.  ALl this depends on how you are managing states, persistence of states, etc.

Overall, the answer is not simple unless other details are provided. 
I am providing a separate answer, rather than a comment because I BELIEVE THAT TOO MANY DEVELOPERS USE EXPRESS AND THEREBY LIMIT THEIR FLEXIBILITY.

Comment: Sure, maybe you can do more advanced stuff without express, but it's quicker. It's like saying you wouldn't use jquery and only vanilla javascript. The commands are shorter and it makes writing code more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

Going somewhat against the flow I would have to say that I don't see how doing something like that makes sense. Node.js has a one process design constrain. Throttling IO is hard work for one web application let alone a few. Trying to abstract that by having several applications will over complicate the code making it unreadable. A bug in a single application can impact all applications. This is a very unstable configuration.

If you're looking to see if you can do it, I guess the answer is yes. Something like vhost suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11961884/780027) in another answer.  On the other hand, I would probably go with some kind of separation of concerns and constrain my app. If it's to be placed in the same server box I would do the following:

1. The number of available cores -1 will be the number of domains I would bind to a single server.
2. Each core will hold a node.js process bounded to it. It will implement a single web application covering a single website.
3. the spare core will hold some kind of a "router", either an nginx solution or another node.js/express application which routes the data.

In short, don't think about going big, think about going wide.

Drawback:
It's a different way of scaling. There is only so much of juice you can get out of a single box. I'm not sure how to scale this idea when we are talking about a "multi-box" environment.