# Domain mapping (allow my users to have custom domains)

Tags: reactjs, dns, subdomain

Let's assume that I am building an e-commerce SaaS platform with react. Every subscriber of my platform will be able to create an e-commerce site under a subdomain (eg. max.myecom.com), and also have the option to use a custom domain (eg. maxecom.com). How would I approach to do that?

I'm sorry if it is a dumb question, but I am new to react and to javascript apps in general.

I do have experience with PHP, and have implemented a similar project using WordPress multisite.

But not even Google gave me an answer to this problem using react.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React is only a frontend framework and can't do anything with subdomains (once it's bundled, it's purely html, css and js that can be served by any html server). You could do the backend for this project in PHP, since you know the language already, or use any other language for this purpose. If you wanted to write the whole project in JavaScript, you would have to play around with Node.js and Express.js [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11960705).